# Group of bytes in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, arrays

I need to store a group of bytes in an Entity Framework table. I would need to store something like `AB` in the following:

```
byte[] a = new byte[]{0xFF,0xFF};
byte[] b = new byte[]{0x01,0x01};
List<byte[]> AB = new List<byte[]>{a,b};
```

But it fails silently for a List of bytes and a multidimensional/jagged byte array. I assume they are not supported.

What is the best (and hopefully inexpensive to process) way to store a group of bytes in an EF database?

Comment: What about storing each byte array in different row as `blob`?

Comment: Sounds interesting but I don't think I get what you mean exactly, can you show me briefly through an answer? How would I make a class for that? @AdilMammadov

Comment: You could just store off the bytes to a an actual file, and just reference the location in the DB

Comment: @CallumLinington great idea but can't use file reads right now - I have to just use EF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store byte array in database as `blob`. Create a model like:

```
public class DataModel
{
    public int DataModelID { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can store each byte array as a row in `DataModel` table:

```
// Initialize data
List<DataModel> dataModels = new List<DataModel>
{
    new DataModel { Data = new byte[]{0xFF,0xFF} },
    new DataModel { Data = new byte[]{0x01,0x01} }
};

// Add it to database
using(MyContext context = new MyContext())
{
    context.DataModels.Add(dataModels);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now you have your byte arrays in database with their PKs and you can relate them with what you want using their `DataModelID`s.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now. I actually thought about this but I thought it was a little too much...but if this is the best way I guess I'll go with this

Comment: @Tyress, I do not know your needs so I cannot tell if it is *a liitle too much* according to your situation and actually I do not know if it is the best way, but it is the way which I know :)